# Dell DA310 dock is stuck in USB2

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, hardware, docking

I own a [Dell inspiron 5415](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/laptops/inspiron-14-laptop/spd/inspiron-14-5415-laptop/cn51108), and a [usb-c dock DA310](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-usb-c-mobile-adapter-da310/apd/470-aeup/pc-accessories)

when I run ubuntu 21.10, kernel 5.13.0-23-generic, the dock is recognized as usb2, despite it is usb3, (I tested this with an external usb3 disk and I only get 40mb/s debit). I plug this dock to the only USB-C port, which is indeed an 3.1gen2 port.

here is >usb-devices command output, that shows Ver = 2.01:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=03 Port=05 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=c010 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Dell
S:  Product=Dell DA310
S:  SerialNumber=11AD1D0A80CB3D08262D0B00
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=11(blbrd) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

When I run windows 10, it is running with usb3 bandwidth and speed.
Any idea how can it be recognize it as usb3 or how can I force Linux to use a usb3 drivers ?

I you need additional command output just let me know.

Thanks,

Sinn'

Comment: You probably need to update the firmware on the dock. See the dell web site.

Comment: Oh dear, I did not think about that... Went to to dell and updated DA310 firmware and also the bios firmware from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 which was flagged as critical update
now my usb disk has usb3 debit. thx @heynnema.

Comment: @sinner73 Please could you share information on how you updated the firmware for the DA310? On Dell's website, I can see there is a firmware update tool for Windows, but nothing for Linux.

Comment: @James Sometimes FreeDOS can work when you don't have access to Windows. http://www.freedos.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

You need to update the firmware on the dock. See the dell web site.

*Went to to dell and updated DA310 firmware and also the bios firmware from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 which was flagged as critical update now my usb disk has usb3 debit.*

Answer (score 0):

heynnema's answer helped me, but here's some elaboration:

The tool you need to update the DA310 firmware is called: "DA310 FW-updater".  It is only available for windows, so you'll need access to a Windows machine to continue (this was difficult for me).

After doing this, I had the device working well on Debian.

One red-haring in this question is the output of `usb-devices` doesn't change after updating the firmware, so `Ver= 2.01` does not indicate you need to update the firmware.

```
$ usb-devices | grep -c 4 DA310
T:  Bus=03 Lev=02 Prnt=50 Port=04 Cnt=02 Dev#= 52 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=413c ProdID=c010 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Dell
S:  Product=Dell DA310
S:  SerialNumber=11AD1D0A6BA83E1625130B00
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=11(blbrd) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=03 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Sometimes FreeDOS can work when you don't have access to Windows. http://www.freedos.org/